# How to get wp_attachment_metadata in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, metadata

I am using wordpress, and i want to get wp_attachment_metadata in my own way. In case, i want to separate the sizes (Thumbnail, Large, Medium, Small) . The meta value on database contains an array like this  :

a:5:{s:5:"width";i:660;s:6:"height";i:320;s:4:"file";s:39:"2013/07/debut-busana-muslim-new-yor.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:2:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:39:"debut-busana-muslim-new-yor-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:39:"debut-busana-muslim-new-yor-300x145.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:145;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";i:0;s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}

Well, i am stuck. I dont know how to separate that array. Anyone knows how to separate that array in order i can get the sizes and the url of the images.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand i think you want to extract the values.
This is the [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) data stored in the database, you can separate it with [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function.

http://codepad.org/7VgwLTth